# Using the MSI database to detect feature state

Tags: windows-installer

I have an MSI containing six different features. The software installed via the MSI runs in a distributed environment (each feature can be installed on a different machine, run from a single machine, or any combination). I am creating an update routine that will coordinate an update across all the different machines if necessary. The first phase of the routine is to update my database schema (one of the MSI features). If the update is successful I continue to update the remaining features. Is there a way, using C#, to use the MSI Database to determine the install state of a feature? Basically, I want to run the check on every machine and determine which one has the database feature installed.

Comment: It's not the MSI database rather the Windows Installer service metabase to query.  What programming language do you want to do this in?

Comment: @ChristopherPainter c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I don't really understand why you need all of this.  If you are using Minor Upgrades the same features and components will be reinstalled unless you specify otherwise or use transitive/conditional components.   During a MajorUpgrade you can tell your UpgradeTable entry to migrate feature states and you'll get the same features you got before.  So the MSI should just run on every machine and simply work.

That said, if you want to detect feature states using C# get Windows Installer XML (WiX) and take a look at Deployment Tools Foundation (DTF).  DTF has an interop library for Windows Installer called Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll and you use it like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ProductInstallation productInstallation = new ProductInstallation("{4500F118-6DC7-4A77-94BF-F2409486D8E1}", null, UserContexts.Machine);
            foreach (var feature in productInstallation.Features)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is {1}", feature.FeatureName, feature.State.ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Finished");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

> IWD_GENERALINFORMATION is Local
>
> IWD is Local
>
> IWD_NAMESPACES is Local
>
> IWD_PROPERTIES is Local
>
> IWD_FILESANDFOLDERS is Local
>
> IWD_CUSTOMTABLES is Local
>
> IWD_XMLEDITOR is Local
>
> IW is Local
>
> ISWIXADDIN is Local
>
> IWD_SERVICES is Absent
>
> IWD_SHORTCUTS is Absent
>
> Finished

Comment: The reason is if the database feature fails I do not want the other features to be updated so they can continue to work with the previous schema. So I determine which box contains the database feature, run the update, and set some state so the other updates (on separate boxes) know they can proceed.

Comment: FWIW, I'd do this different. I'd make it an application problem not an installer problem.  An example is Team Foundation Server installation.  You can install the new version but then you go into the admin console and service the project collection database to upgrade the schema.

Comment: That is what I am doing. There is a service that controls the update process. The service is what executes the code above and coordinates the multiple update processes. To do the actual update I am using msiexec with the RESINSTALL property set to the features I want to update.

Comment: Have you just tried using REINSTALL=ALL?  Per the following link REINSTALL=ALL only reinstalls features that were previously installed. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371175(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Yes. However, if the database feature is present I do not want to run it again so I use the explicit features.

Comment: Write the SQL scripts so that when they execute again they realize that the steps are already done and can fall through.  Remember to test the "repair" story of your installer.